# Symfony 3.1 Ldap Authentication Not Working

Tags: php, authentication, ldap, symfony

I am developing an application using Symfony 3.1 and I am having problems on Ldap authentication. The following code:

services.yml

```
ldap:
    class: 'Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient'
    arguments:
        - server.test.br   # host
        - 389         # port
        - 3           # version
        - false       # SSL
        - false        # TLS
```

security.yml

```
security:
providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [my_ldap]
    my_ldap:
        ldap:
            service: ldap
            base_dn: dc=test,dc=br
            search_dn: cn=s00027,ou=Contas Administrativas de Sistemas,ou=Departamento de Tecnologia,dc=test,dc=br
            search_password: pass
            default_roles: ROLE_USER
            uid_key: sAMAccountName
            filter:  '({uid_key}={username})'

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    admin:
        anonymous: true
        pattern:   ^/
        form_login_ldap:
            provider: chain_provider
            service: ldap
            dn_string: 'sAMAccountName={username}'
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /

    default:
        form_login_ldap:
            provider: chain_provider
            service: ldap
            dn_string: "uid={username},DC=test,DC=br"
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

SecurityController.php

```
 /**
 * @Route("/login_check", name="login_check")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request) {

    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render(
                    'AppBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(
                // last username entered by the user
                'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                'error' => $error,
                    )
    );
}
```

I have tried everything I could and received no errors at logs, only the message about LdapClient class is deprecated.

Could anyone help me? Please.

Comment: Have you checked in the `var/logs/dev.log` and tried using the DEV environment by appending `app_dev.php` to your URL? The debug URL might show more information.

Comment: Yes! I have searched all Stackoverflow tutorials for symfony 3.1 and ldap, and no success. But, thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Is this AD or OpenLDAP? From the looks of `sAMAccountName` use I would guess AD? If so change `dn_string: 'sAMAccountName={username}'` to `dn_string: '{username}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Symfony 3 developers!

I solved the problem using [LdapToolsBundle](https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools-bundle)

I think the problem was not using Guard although is Symfony 3.1. But, using LdapTools solved my problem and it is very easy to work with.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the Symfony LDAP solution doesn't work, you may have to go with "FR3DLdapBundle" and FOSBundle.

I have a tutorial here:
https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/03/25/symfony-ad-integration/

This definitely works, since I use it all the time.

---

EDIT #2

I created a second article that makes AD Authentication easier:
https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2017/09/07/symfony-ldap-component-ad-authentication/

I should solve your issues mentioned above.